# DatePicker/TimePicker format in WP7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, controls

I have nice UI with DatePicker and TimePicker but I need to change the final look of variables which they give.

Date looks like that: 28/02/2012
Time looks like that: 09:18

I would like to have it in SQL DateTime format, so I have two questions:

1) How to change separators in date?
2) How to convert it into SQL format: 2012-02-28 09:18

The only idea what I have in my mind now is to take each part (year, month..etc.) and manually make new datetime variable. Also here I have question. If I will have good format, can I send it to database as a string?

Comment: I have found semi-solution: change regional settings. It will work in my scenario, but topic to discuss for more universal apps

Comment: Arguably, you shouldn't change the format, to be as helpful as possible to those using your application - if you need to send it somewhere else in a different string format, then you should handle that conversion yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the [System.Threading.Thread.CurrentUICulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) and/or [System.Threading.Thread.CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to a custom Culture instance that returns the date & time in the format you require!